# Splunk Query Count of Count

Tags: splunk

I want to know the count of a count of a query.
The query is

```
sourcetype="cargo_dc_shipping_log" OR sourcetype="cargo_dc_deliver_log" | stats count by X_REQUEST_ID | sort - count
```

[image]

So you can see there are multiple rows with the value of 3.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're goal in this particular case is to get a summary of counts for this *X_REQUEST_ID* field, right?

Let's take your initial query:

> sourcetype="cargo_dc_shipping_log" OR sourcetype="cargo_dc_deliver_log" | stats count by X_REQUEST_ID | sort - count

What we're missing here is how to aggregate against your aggregation. *Then*, we can sort:

> sourcetype="cargo_dc_shipping_log" OR sourcetype="cargo_dc_deliver_log" | stats count as req_count by X_REQUEST_ID | stats count by req_count | sort - count

Let me know if that works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe another stats count command at the end of your original query like so:

```
sourcetype="cargo_dc_shipping_log" OR sourcetype="cargo_dc_deliver_log" | stats count by X_REQUEST_ID | stats count
```

This would give you a single result with a count field equal to the number of search results.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Just pipe your search to stats count.

```
...your search query|stats count
```